# Ready to use translations for Delphi's built-in strings?

Tags: delphi, localization, translation

I am localizing my application in Delphi XE3. After adding a language, I find many strings in the Translation Manager are actually from the built-in units, such as `VCL.Consts`, `System.RTLConsts`, etc. For such strings, I just wonder if there are any read-to-use translated strings available so that I do not need to translate them myself?

Answer (score 3):

Delphi comes with the sources for the RTL/VCL, and some subdirectories for the languages German, French and Japanese (depending on what you selected during installation). They contain units with the resource strings for these languages. Unfortunately, these translations are not complete, as some 3rd party code apparently wasn't translated.

[dxgettext](http://dxgettext.po.dk/) comes with [translations](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/dxgettext/code/trunk/translations/) for the RTL/VCL and several libraries (e.g. Indy, Rave Reports) for several languages. The last Delphi version I could find there is Delphi XE2 for German (support for other languages stopped much earlier, or doesn't exist at all). I have no idea how complete it is.

There used to be a website where you could submit such translations, but it went down many years ago.

Currently I am using the German Delphi XE2 translations for Delphi 10.2 and haven't seen any missing ones, but I am sure there are.